# Coral Dev Board Mini with Enviromental Sensor Board GPIO problems

Tags: python, gpio, arm64, google-coral

I use the Environmental Sensor Board with my Google Coral Dev Board Mini.
And all kind of GPIO calls directly on the board lead to the same error, In this example

```
from periphery import GPIO
gpio = GPIO(138, "low")

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
periphery.gpio.GPIOError: [Errno 22] Exporting GPIO: Invalid argument
```

Details:

```
Linux 4.19.125-mtk #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 10 02:36:13 UTC 2020 aarch64

Mendel GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
mendel@zippy-orange:~$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from periphery import GPIO
>>> gpio = GPIO(138, "low")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/periphery/gpio.py", line 1007, in _open
    f_export.write("{:d}\n".format(line))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/periphery/gpio.py", line 988, in __init__
    self._open(line, direction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/periphery/gpio.py", line 1009, in _open
    raise GPIOError(e.errno, "Exporting GPIO: " + e.strerror)
periphery.gpio.GPIOError: [Errno 22] Exporting GPIO: Invalid argument
>>>
```

I have the same issue with the Google enviro_demo.py:
`enviro = EnviroBoard()`
same errors.

Any ideas? All has been installed from scratch/flash :) just minutes ago.
Thank you.

Best,
Frank

Comment: Does the code based on `libgpiod` work on this board? Do the `libgpiod` shell tools work?

Comment: I think it is not needed but it is good for debugging so I installed it. Looks like the board is not found maybe a DOA, esp. the little LED on the EnviroBoard does not light up...

Comment: Be sure that your kernel provides necessary interfaces (GPIO character device) to the user space.

Comment: This image/kernel flashed to the board has been provided by Google I really hope they did that :) The documentation is straightforward for the board: [link]https://coral.ai/docs/enviro-board/get-started/#1-attach-the-sensor-board And ```gpioinfo``` lists a ```gpiochip0``` with some used lines but not the needed.

Answer (score 0):

For all, I got this answer from Coral support:

"[...] I had a discussion with the team here and came to know that the Dev board mini and Enviro board do not work together as of now.

We don't have a timeline on when this combination will be supported.

Thanks Coral Support Team [...]"